# Работа с фрагментами android listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с работой с фрагментами. Создал фрагмент с listview. Пишу код:

```
package com.example.a1.test3.fragments;


import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.a1.test3.R;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Fragment2#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    final String FILENAME = "file";
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String res = "";


    public Fragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment2.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment2 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }          
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, null, false);
        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // определяем массив типа String
        final String[] catNames = new String[] {
            "Рыжик", "Барсик", "Мурзик", "Мурка", "Васька",
            "Томасина", "Кристина", "Пушок", "Дымка", "Кузя",
            "Китти", "Масяня", "Симба"
        };

        // используем адаптер данных
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catNames);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }
```

Теперь такая ошибка:

```
09-17 10:52:32.365 17241-17241/com.example.a1.test3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.example.a1.test3, PID: 17241
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.example.a1.test3.fragments.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:104)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Вот разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_for_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите весь код фрагмента и его разметку

Comment: Добавил код и разметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не в том месте ищите `ListView` по его `ID` при инициализации.

Искать надо не в активити, но в разметке фрагмента. Разметка фрагмента загружается в метода `onCreateView` именно там и надо инициализировать `ListView`. Вот код (не помню конкретных сигнатур методов)

```
ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null, false);
    listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    return v;
}
```

Так у вас `ListView` будет полем класса и вы сможете к нему обращаться после вызова `onCreateView`.

Также вам надо перенести весь код из `onCreate` в `onCreateView`, т.к. в `onCreate` разметка ещё не загружена и к `ListView` обратиться никак нельзя

Comment: Попробовал исправить, как вы посоветовали, но что-то пошло не так

Comment: @Сашка, вы из метода `onCreateView` возвращаете не то. Вы дважды разметку загружаете. А надо возвращать ту, что уже загрузили. Перечитайте ещё раз код в моём ответе. И проверьте какую именно разметку вам надо. У вас в коде 2 разных.

Comment: Разметку исправил, не заметил. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Сашка если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)